# I can´t create a new folder

Tags: solidity, remix, web3.py, python, create

I am very busy because I can´t create a simple folder. Remix, I created a new folder but No make anything, and Remix is in no function. I am a new student of remix, can you help me?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are talking about. Please rephrase and give examples or screenshots.

Comment: Hello, the problem I have is that every time I try to create a new remix file it shows me the line to enter the name of the file and after that it does nothing. I have read some answers from all of you but I have not found a clarifying answer.

Comment: @Henry What browser are you using? Can you try with another broswer? Make sure to **backup** your contract before trying the next. Clear the cookies/database for the remix page.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to understand your problem but as i understand your question if you are not able to create folder on remix this is how you can create folder on remix
[image]

At the end file you can create folder

Comment: I know where you can create a file but no matter how many times I try Remix it doesn't execute anything, I don't know if you understood me.

Comment: Did it show you error ? If no then it is possible your network issue.

Comment: If still you don't got your answer then we can arrange a meeting